# Make case fans work RaspberryPi4

Tags: hardware, power

I've loaded my RPi4 with **CentOS7**
I also bought a case with fans that you can attach to the pins on the pi.

I'm not sure where to start looking for the software modifications I need to make in order to power the fans.

Comment: Is the fan simply meant to run continuously; in which case it only needs to connect to power and ground? What does the product listing say? Have you searched for raspberry pi temp controlled fan?

Answer (score 3):

Some fans supplied with cases are designed to run full-time. If that's what you're doing, you don't need **any** software - just connect the fan wiring to the appropriate GPIO pins. If you're asking how to switch the fan ON & OFF based on the RPi CPU temperature, read on.

AFAIK CentOS7 - like all other Linux OS distributed by "The Foundation" - uses the same/standard *device tree* configuration that RPi OS does. That being the case, the only "software modification" you need to make is to add a single line to your `/boot/config.txt` file that invokes the *device tree overlay* named `gpio-fan`.

You can confirm this overlay is available on your system by checking that the file `/boot/overlays/gpio-fan.dtbo` exists on your system. This one-liner will give you that information:

```bsh
$ [[ -f /boot/overlays/gpio-fan.dtbo ]] && echo "fan-overlay available" || echo "No fan-overlay; write a script instead"
```

If you must (or prefer) to write a script, there are [many examples here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=cooling+fan) to do that.

To use the `gpio-fan overlay`, you will find a ***brief*** explanation for many of the available overlays in your local file `/boot/overlays/README` or on [GitHub](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README); the current version copied here:

```
Name:   gpio-fan
Info:   Configure a GPIO pin to control a cooling fan.
Load:   dtoverlay=gpio-fan,<param>=<val>
Params: gpiopin                 GPIO used to control the fan (default 12)
        temp                    Temperature at which the fan switches on, in
                                millicelcius (default 55000)
```

What this means:

##### Step 1:

Turning a fan ON & OFF requires an external switch (e.g. transistor) as the GPIO pin itself is not up to the task. Instead - use the GPIO to control the transistor. Connect your 2-wire, 3.3V or 5V fan as shown in the diagram below. See the [GPIO pinout page](https://pinout.xyz/#) for available GPIO pins.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGZ5L8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you're wondering how to add this hardware to your system, there is a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1FQojoaNS8) that has some ideas - it was referenced in [one of the many "fan answers"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117596/83790) here.

##### Step 2:

Add the overlay to `/boot/config.txt` as follows:

```
dtoverlay=gpio-fan,gpiopin=5,temp=60000
```

`reboot` to load the overlay. Using the settings above, your fan will turn on when the temperature reaches 60deg C & turn off when it falls a few degrees below that.

Comment: *"If CentOS7 uses the standard device tree configuration that RPi OS does"* -> Might be worth noting, so that someone does not waste too much time pursuing that as a cause of problems, that since the RPi requires a special kernel and it is the kernel + firmware that apply the device tree stuff, it almost certainly is supported anywhere and everywhere.   That said, CentOS following RHEL is very conservative update wise and you should check `/boot/overlays` for `gpio-fan.dtbo`.  If it isn't there, this can't work, if it is, it should.