# How to control Raspberry Pi case fan with code (not pi temperature)

Tags: gpio, pi-4

I was wondering if it is possible to directly control the case fan included with some of the Raspberry Pis. Lots of posts tell you how to turn it on or off when the Raspberry Pi gets to a certain temperature, but I want to use it for other purposes.

Is there a way to turn the 2 pin GPIO fan on or off depending on the time for example?

Comment: Try this link and see if it is close. https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/2nc4z5/my_homemade_raspberry_pi_smart_thermostat/  You will need some code, a sensor, and a driver for your fan. Post a schematic of how you will connect it showing all connections power, ground and power supplies.

Comment: How could we know?  What fan?

Answer (score 0):

That will depend entirely upon **how** the fan is wired, and what type of fan it is. Since you didn't provide these details, the only answer you can get is something like this:

Assuming your fan is powered from the 3.3V bus, **and** its current is limited to a [*"safe value"*](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#what-is-a-safe-current), the answer to your question is clearly, ***"Yes"***. WRT wiring your fan, [another answer here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117596/83790) contains a schematic that may be useful.