# Lower temperature for GPIO fan turning on

Tags: raspi-config, cooling

`raspi-config P4` only allows temperatures above 60, but I prefer being able to touch my pi before the fan turns on. Is there a way to ignore this limit and set the temperature to a lower value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a single line  needs to be added to `config.txt`

```
dtoverlay=gpio-fan,temp=60000
```

to switch the fan on at 60℃  - 60000 millicelcius (the default is 55℃ but you can select any temperature). The fan turns off when the temperature falls by 10℃.

This uses the `gpio-fan` overlay (which has been available in the kernel since late 2018) and should be included in recent versions of Raspbian. (Read `/boot/overlays/README` for description of this and other Device Tree overlays.)

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105820/8697

Answer (score 0):

Reading the code in raspi-config, it sets the following in `config.txt`

```
dtoverlay=gpio-fan,gpiopin=x,temp=y
```

replace `x` with the gpiopin the fan control is connected to
replace `y` with the trigger temperature in millicelcius

If you've played with the `P4` already you should see the `dtoverlay=gpio-fan` line in `config.txt` already, so you just need to edit that and reboot