# Raspberry Pi pwm fan control

Tags: pwm, cooling

I have a PWM fan connected to pin 18
What is the simplest way to make the fan turn on at 50 degrees and turn off when the temperature drops to 35 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/133849/8697 explains how to turn a fan on/off at a given temperature.

Normally PWM fans use varied speeds but these need a controller and there are Device Tree overlays for these.
I am not aware of any existing code using GPIO pins - you really don't need to use hardware PWM.

The Pi5 has an inbuilt fan control.