# Where to make electronic connections diagrams

Tags: pi-zero-w, connection

I'm making a little project with a raspberry pi zero, for documentation purposes I'd like to add some connection diagrams/representations, my main purpose is to have an easy reference to see pin numbers, connections between motors, motor controllers, power sources, lcd displays, etc, I'd like the result to be something like this:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

These examples are just for illustrative purposes, result doesn't have to support protoboards or raspberry pi logos but I'd be really pleased if application/platform supported pin numbers or the possibility to customize my own components if not included in the platform.

I've used [lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/es) to create flowcharts and seems like this could be an option but if you happen to know a similar tool which supports electronic diagrams and "drag and drop" or similar that would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Those illustrations are produced by Fritzing. While they may be of use for demonstrating layout they are a poor way of documenting a project. The raspberrypi.stackexchange.com Edit has a schematic tool which is far more useful. Examples https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105820/8697 https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118117/8697

Comment: The schematic at the top of the second link actually isn't circuitlab (the thing used here, there is a button in the editor for it), but there are several further down that are.  It is also a great tool for hypothesizing and learning about circuits since there is a "simulate" feature.  LucidCharts is quite nice but not so much for electronic schematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal choice is KiCad. It is a full blown CAD (Computer Aided Design) program that is free unless you want to make a donation. It is not something you will become proficient in a few days unless you have had previous experience with CAD. I use it for schematic capture through Gerber files for PCBs. It will also generate a 3-D view of your potential PCB (Printed Circuit Board). There are several other CAD programs available, you need will to check and see which you like. Some are complete and unlimited like KiCad while other are limited in some way. Limits may be number of components, board size, etc. I use Linux and for documentation I prefer a screenshot which I can crop and edit any way I want.

Answer (score 1):

I've used org chart software to make diagrams in the past. You may check to see what LibreOffice can do:
https://elearn.ellak.gr/mod/assign/view.php?id=2859
NOTE: trying to do it with a flow chart will probably be more frustrating, but you may be able to mangle an org chart into something pretty. Otherwise, a presentation?