# Is it possible to control the 5V supply (e.g. pin 4) via python?

Tags: python, power-supply

I want to (de)activate a fan, which is connected to the pins 4 and 6, depending on the temperature of the CPU.

Is it possible to (de)activate Pin 4 (or Pin 2) at the Raspberry Pi 4 via python? I have already read this article: [How to turn power off on 5V dc gpio pin with python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/how-to-turn-power-off-on-5v-dc-gpio-pin-with-python), but is there another way just via python, without using a transistor?

Comment: This question has been asked dozens of times. You could write a program, but there is no need. The kernel has inbuilt fan control https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105820/8697

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn power off on 5V dc gpio pin with python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/how-to-turn-power-off-on-5v-dc-gpio-pin-with-python)

Comment: I've already read this post, but I just wanted to assure myself. Thanks for the upper link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Pin 6 is connected to the Pi's ground rail.

Pins 2 and 4 are connected to the Pi's 5V rail.

Comment: So the real only possibility is to interrupt the power circuit?

Comment: @Meiki Yes, with a switch, e.g. manual switch, relay, transistor etc.

Comment: But is it possible to control the transistor via python, e.g. via using a GPIO-pin?

Comment: Yes.  Plenty of answers showing how.

Comment: This other question in this forum provides more information. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95710/how-to-program-active-cooling-connected-to-gpio